# I want to groupby and drop groups if the shape is 3 and non of the values from a column contains zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to groupby and drop groups if it satisfies two conditions (the shape is 3 and column A doesn't contain zeros).

My df

```
ID  value
A    3
A    2
A    0
B    1
B    1
C    3
C    3
C    4
D    0
D    5
D    5
E    6
E    7
E    7
F    3
F    2
```

my desired df would be

```
ID  value
A    3
A    2
A    0
B    1
B    1
D    0
D    5
D    5
F    3
F    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing with `groupby` operations:

```
g = df['value'].eq(0).groupby(df['ID'])

# group contains a 0
m1 = g.transform('any')
# group doesn't have size 3
m2 = g.transform('size').ne(3)

# keep if any of the condition above is met
# this is equivalent to dropping if contains 0 AND size 3
out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
   ID  value
0   A      3
1   A      2
2   A      0
3   B      1
4   B      1
8   D      0
9   D      5
10  D      5
14  F      3
15  F      2
```

Comment: if there a way to do this in one liner? hopefully w `filter`?

Comment: I believe `filter` would be slower than this.

Comment: That would be `df.groupby ('ID').filter(lambda g: (0 in g['value']) or (len(g['value']) != 3))`, but as QuangHoang mentioned, `filter` is usually slow.